# Create the same handler for all the controls of my form?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to add the same handler to all my controls in my form. Here is my code :

```
Sub CreateDelegates()
    For Each Ctl In Me.Controls
        AddHandler Ctl.MouseDown, AddressOf MainPictureBox_MouseDown
    Next
End Sub
```

The problem is that `MouseDown` is not recognised as an event of `Object`. Any idea of how to solve that ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have `Option Infer On`?  if not, try `For Each Ctl As Control In Me.Controls`.

Comment: I don't know but this worked. Thanks mate.

Comment: Option Infer doesn't solve this, it infers Object because Controls implements the non-generic IEnumerable.  Please close your question.

Comment: It's done now, I couldn't before because if the timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
For Each Ctl As Control In Me.Controls
  AddHandler Ctl.MouseDown, AddressOf MainPictureBox_MouseDown
Next
```

If these are all PictureBox controls, then it might be better to filter them:

```
For Each Ctl As PictureBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)()
  AddHandler Ctl.MouseDown, AddressOf MainPictureBox_MouseDown
Next
```

Comment: No they're not, it's just a copy / paste of a function I had already done in another window where I only needed this handler on a PictureBox.